# spread for duplicate identifiers

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I'm really sorry to ask this question again, because there are already many questions about this. However, none of the solutions worked for my problem.

My data looks like this:

```
id scale rater rating  
1   A      1      5
1   B      1      7
1   A      2      3
1   B      2      6
2   A      1      4
2   B      1      3
2   A      2      2
2   B      2      1
```

I want to `spread(rater, rating)`

In the end it should look like this:

```
id scale   1      2  
1   A      5      3
1   B      7      6
2   A      4      2
2   B      3      1
```

The problem obviously is that the rows in the first dataset don't have unique identifiers. Looking at answers to similar questions, none of the solutions seem to work for me. I can't just delete duplicate rows and when using row numbers or grouped identifiers `group_by(id) %>%
  mutate (grouped_id = row_number())` I don't get the two raters put in one column, but a row each with NA for the rating of the other rater.

I feel like I tried everything I could find and would really appreciate some help! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`spread`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html) function, without having to `group_by` anything (thanks @Jaap):

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
    spread(rater, rating)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id scale   `1`   `2`
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1     1 A         5     3
2     1 B         7     6
3     2 A         4     2
4     2 B         3     1
```

#### Edit using `reshape`

Although I would *almost never* advise using the `reshape` function over the `gather` and `spread` functions, here's how you could do it using base R:

```
reshape(dat, direction = 'wide',
        idvar = c('id','scale'),
        v.names = 'rating',
        timevar = 'rater')

  id scale rating.1 rating.2
1  1     A        5        3
2  1     B        7        6
5  2     A        4        2
6  2     B        3        1
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
               scale = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
               rater = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
               rating = c(5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: no need for a `group_by`; just `dat %>% spread(rater, rating)` works